# css image not displaying in codeigniter 3.10

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, xampp

my home page looks like

[image]

when i click on five species it displays like this
[image]

config.php in application folder.

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/antimalarial/';    
$config['index_page'] = "index.php?";    
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$config['error_views_path'] = '';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;
$config['encryption_key'] = '';
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '';
$config['cookie_path']  = '/';
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
$config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

routes.php in config folder.

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'Welcome';
$route['(:any)'] = 'Welcome/$1';
```

Welcome.php in Controller folder

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

 /**
  * Index Page for this controller.
  *
  * Maps to the following URL
  *   http://example.com/index.php/welcome
  * - or -
  *   http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
  * - or -
  * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
  * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
  *
  * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
  * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
  * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
  */
 
 public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        
    }
 public function index()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('home.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function home()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('home.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function fivespecies()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('fivespecies.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function parasite()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('parasite.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function definite()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('definite.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function currenttools()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('currenttools.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function malariatreatment()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('malariatreatment.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function history()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('history.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function Areasofwork()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('Areasofwork.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function mapofprojects()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('mapofprojects.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function toolkits()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('toolkits.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function globalmalariamapper()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('globalmalariamapper.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function aboutus()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('aboutus.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function faq()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('faq.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function privacy()
 {
     $this->load->view('header.php'); 
            $this->load->view('privacy.php');
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
 }
 public function feedback() {

        if (isset($_POST ['feedsubmit'])) {

            $in_name = $this->input->post('name');
            $in_email = $this->input->post('email');
            $in_college = $this->input->post('college');
            $in_phone = $this->input->post('phone');
            $in_message = $this->input->post('message');

            $result = $this->USER_MODEL->add_new_feedback($in_name, $in_email, $in_college, $in_phone, $in_message);

            if ($result) {
                echo "<script>alert('Feed Submitted Succesfully');</script>";
                unset($_POST);
                $this->feedback();
                //redirect(base_url() . "feedback");
            } else {
                echo "<script>alert('Feed Already Submitted');</script>";
                unset($_POST);
                $this->feedback();
                //redirect(base_url() . "feedback");
            }
        } else {
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('feedback');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
    }
}
```

header.php in view folder.

```html
<!-- === BEGIN HEADER === -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <!-- Title -->
        <title>Database for antimalarial Drug</title>
        <!-- Meta -->
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Template CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/nexus.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Google Fonts-->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="body-bg">
            <!-- Phone/Email -->
            <div id="pre-header" class="background-gray-lighter">
                <div class="container no-padding">
                    <div class="row hidden-xs">
                         <!--<div class="col-sm-6 padding-vert-5">
                            <strong>Phone:</strong>&nbsp;9030051219
                        </div>-->
      
         
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Phone/Email -->
            <!-- Header -->
            <div id="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Logo -->
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="index.html" title="">
                                <img src="assets/img/logo1.png" alt="Logo" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Logo -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Header -->
            <!-- Top Menu -->
            <div id="hornav" class="bottom-border-shadow">
                <div class="container no-padding border-bottom">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 no-padding">
                            <div class="visible-lg">
                                <ul id="hornavmenu" class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="index.html" class="fa-home ">home</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="fa-gears  ">Malaria</span>
                                        <ul>
                                            
                                            
                                    
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Welcome/fivespecies">five Species</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Welcome/parasite">Parasite life cycle</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Welcome/definite">Definite and symptoms</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Welcome/currenttools">Current tools</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Welcome/malariatreatment">Malaria Treatment</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Welcome/history">History of antimalarials</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="fa-copy  ">Access</span>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Welcome/Areasofwork">Areas of work</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Welcome/mapofprojects">Map of Projects</a>
                                            </li>                                            
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Welcome/toolkits">Tool kits</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Welcome/globalmalariamapper">Global malaria mapper</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Welcome/fivespecies">Access interviews</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="fa-th  ">News room</span>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="portfolio-2-column.html">News</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="portfolio-3-column.html">Press Releases</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="portfolio-4-column.html">Publications</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="portfolio-6-column.html">Events</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="fa-font  ">Blog</span>
                                        
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="contact.html" class="fa-comment ">Drugs</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 no-padding">
                            <ul class="social-icons pull-right">
                                <li class="social-youtube">
                                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/MMVMeds4Malaria" target="_blank" title="Youtube"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="social-twitter">
                                    <a href="https://twitter.com/MalariaNoMore?lang=en" target="_blank" title="Twitter"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="social-facebook">
                                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Antimalarial-medication/111604075529955" target="_blank" title="Facebook"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="social-googleplus">
                                    <a href="https://plus.google.com/114702323662314783325" target="_blank" title="Google+"></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Top Menu -->
            <!-- === END HEADER === -->
```

.htaccess file

```html
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That is quite a bit of code for a question simplify it perhaps

Comment: also if your view file is a php you don't need to add .php `$this->load->view('header');` see if adding true helps also on header and footer like `$this->load->view('header', '', true);` https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data

Comment: On config change this `$config['index_page'] = "index.php?";` to `$config['index_page'] = "";`  or if you need index.php remove ? `$config['index_page'] = "index.php"; `

Answer (score 1):

Change your htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

also changed for all file path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

Goto you config and change it to:

```
base_url http://localhost/
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller constructor load URL helper using

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

In your view files....make the script and css path as below(for all)

Example:

Replace

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

With

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Make sure that your assets folder must be in root folder.

Comment: Where your assets folder is located? note: it should be in root dir,

Comment: #nikhilesh kumar also change the image src from [src="assets/img/logo1.png"] to [src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/logo1.png');?>"]

Comment: after editing it changed whole home page to without css

Comment: just inspect and see what is your error.The ways of linking is correct,

Answer (score 0):

add assets/ to all link in css
Example
        assets/css/nexus.css" rel="stylesheet">